# I am using MBtiles for offline map in iOS app, how to merge updated MB tiles with old one. I am using mac system

Tags: ios, macos, mbtiles

I have updated MBtiles as a new file and want to merge with existing main MBtiles file, how can I do that in MAC OS system.

Simply I want to update the MBtiles, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You might try using [mbutil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil) to export the tiles from both MBTiles files and then import them into a new MBTiles file.  You'd need to do something like this:

```
mb-util InputFile1.mbtiles /path/to/directory
mb-util InputFile2.mbtiles /path/to/directory
mb-util /path/to/directory OutputFile.mbtiles
```